# android stop old thread if new thread run in 30 sec

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a broadcastreceiver, in which I have a thread running and after 30 sec it changes the boolean value to true. It is working fine, but the problem is, if broadcastreceiver gets called again before 30 sec, the old thread makes the boolean value to true before 30sec. I want boolean value to be true 30 sec after  the broadcastreceiver is called. However if the receiver runs and before 30 sec it runs again then boolean value changes to true before I want.
Here is code

```
public class ConectivityChangeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


        ListDataTemp.connectivitychanged = false;
        //SettingsActivity.wifiget(context);

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                    ListDataTemp.connectivitychanged = true;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

        t.interrupt();

    }
}
```

Comment: just add `Thread.interrupted()` check where you are setting flag.

Comment: @sohailehmad will you please tell me with some more detail or edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Handler` instance to perform this action:

```
public class ConectivityChangeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if (mHandler == null)
             mHandler = new Handler();
        else
             mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // cancel previous calls

        ListDataTemp.connectivitychanged = false; 
        //SettingsActivity.wifiget(context); 

        Runnable t = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ 
                ListDataTemp.connectivitychanged = true;
            } 
        }; 
        mHandler.postDelayed(t, 30000);

    } 
}
```

Comment: when this handler run?

Comment: The handler call will happen after 30 secs as per ` mHandler.postDelayed(t, 30000);`...if within 30 secs broadcast is called again the previous call will cancel and a new one will be registered which will be triggered after 30 secs

Comment: how to run only once

Comment: It will run once only, after 30 sec delay. Its not gonna repeat unless broadcast is called again.

Comment: yeah, typo.. its `removeCallbacksAndMessages()`

Comment: private Handler mHandler(); mHnadler is method?

Comment: No, typo...I was thinking of instantiating it there and forgot to remove it :D

Comment: its not stop cancel the first handler

Comment: Ok...how your broadcast is being called. Is it registered in the manifest with an <intent-filter>?

Comment: its call when connectivity changed\

Comment: I understand that....I'm trying to figure out if a new instance is being created or the same instance is being called again. I was reading the docs and over there its clearly mentioned (under lifecycle) that broadcasts are bad where asynchronous calls are involved (like above) and they suggest we launch a `Service` instead after receiving a broadcast. The above code will work flawlessly with `Services` since they are single instance only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120580/discussion-between-faisal-iqbal-and-shaishav).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of time and shared preference.

```
public class ConectivityChangeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            Long lastTimeRun=getLastThreadInfo(context);
            if(lastTimeRun>0 && (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimeRun) >30000){
                ListDataTemp.connectivitychanged = true;
            }
            storeLastThreadRunInfo(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    private void storeLastThreadRunInfo(Long time) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", time);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private Long getLastThreadInfo(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getLong("time", 0L);
    }
```